# RoR: trying to indent a the f.text_area of a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to indent this entire form

```
<%= form_for([micropost, micropost.comments.build], :html => { :id => "blah_form" }) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <p2>Who are you?</p2>
      <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <p2>What deal are you offering?</p2>
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Submit"%>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I added `#blah_form` input `{margin-left:80px}` to indent the entire form. 
but the `f.text_area` doesnt indent? When I change it to `f.text_field` it works but I need it to be a `text_area`

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with ROR, it should be tagged under css.

Comment: I figured that the form_for aspect was unique to Ruby on rails. Was this incorrect.

Comment: Yes it is, Whatever style you put in {} will be dumped onto the html tag. Rails doesn't do anything with it. You should be able to see the style on html tag when you inspect it in a browser debugger like firebug. How your page will look is dependent on css rules.

Answer (score 0):

It really should be tagged under css, but when it's already here:

you should try instead of

```
#blah_form input {margin-left:80px}
```

this

```
#blah_form input, textarea {margin-left:80px}
```